# How to fix this issue 'gs: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set'

Tags: imagemagick, alfresco, ghostscript, libreoffice

I uploading .xslx file in alfresco. In tomcat log I have error msg. How fix it?

As I understand Alfresco can't make a thumbnail, maybe a preview, therefore I get this error message

Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 04230034 Failed to perform ImageMagick transformation: 
Execution result: 
   os:         Linux
   command:    /home/asokolov/IdeaProjects/workscope/ThePhone/alfresco-201602-1/common/bin/convert /home/asokolov/IdeaProjects/workscope/ThePhone/alfresco-201602-1/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_source_318024651889008071.pdf[0] -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" /home/asokolov/IdeaProjects/workscope/ThePhone/alfresco-201602-1/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker_target_5704075280585039586.png
   succeeded:  false
   exit code:  1
   out:
   err:        gs: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgs.so.9: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set
.convert.bin: no images defined `/home/asokolov/IdeaProjects/workscope/ThePhone/alfresco-201602-1/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/ImageMagickContentTransformerWorke
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.transformInternal(ImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.java:198)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.AbstractImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.transform(AbstractImageMagickContentTransformerWorker.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer.transformInternal(ProxyContentTransformer.java:100)
    at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:250)
    ... 37 more

Comment: It looks to me like you have a broken Ghostscript installation. Without knowing which version you are using, where you got it from, and how it was built, its rather hard to offer advice. At a guess you have a Ghostscript which was built to use system shared libraries, and you either don't have FreeType installed as a shared library, or you have an incompatible version of FreeType installed. (FT_Property_Set is a FreeType symbol). You could; try installing the latest version of FreeType, take the problem up with the Ghostscript package maintainer or try building GS from source.

Comment: @Kens thanks, I just tried to reinstall gs, ImageMagic, and freeType. After that, I set a path to them in alfresco-global.properties. All work without error, but after I uploaded files, they hadn't had thumbnails and haven't set it after update page

Comment: @KenS perhaps could you help me, please?

Comment: If Ghostscript and ImageMagick are working form the shell, then I'm afraid I cannot offer any further insights. I know nothing about 'alfresco' I'm afraid, possibly it is a different user with different paths.

Comment: Ah, did you actually try running Ghostscript and imagemagick from teh shell, or did you justy try from alfresco ? If you are installing a broken version the re-installign it isn't going to help. Which is why I suggest building it from source. First thing I would try is running GS from the shell.

Comment: The linker error about FT_Property_Set suggests that Freetype is out of date, but given that API call was added in 2.4.11, and the current release is 2.10.0, that would be really *very* out of date. First step would be to check the Freetype version, and second would be to make sure that the libfreetype2 the linker is finding is indeed the one you expect.

Comment: @KenS
I have been tried running ghostscript and imagemagic from the shell and also from alfresco.

Comment: @chrisl Thanks, now I going to check Freetype and libfreetype2.